# SSIS Expression Builder

Tags: ssis, package, expression, builder

I have a file named xyz_20170510_040544_det.txt. 
The date stamp is easier to implement in the expression with get date. The 
problem with time stamp is everyday the time in the file name keeps 
changing. So how do i write the expression in that case

Below is the expression in the ssis expression builder for the package to 
get the file i am using

```
 @[User::DataLoadDir]+"xyz_"+ (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , 
 getdate() ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 
 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +.txt"
```

right now it is unable to find the file because the timestamp is not included. How do i include the time stamp in here because it is different everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apply the following that yields a "yyyymmdd_hhmmss" (20170510_132402) format that you can concatenate with your DataLoadDir variable and ".txt".

(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy" , GETDATE())
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2) + "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("hh" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mi" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("ss" , GETDATE()), 2)

Because I have multiple files being generated with this format, I actually assign this in an expression to one variable and then concatenate that variable for each new file in the Connection Managers.  If you are doing this as well, I recommend the same approach to make your package more modular and avoid redundancy.  Make the change in one variable and it automatically applies everywhere it is used.

However, since you are actually trying to capture a file from a directory that already includes the timestamp and you only want to ready the part up to but not including the timestamp, using the first part of the filename as a wildcard, I recommend the following:

- Apply the following expression to a variable.  This will return just the "xyz_20170510" part of your filename.

  @[User::DataLoadDir]+"xyz_"+ (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , 
  getdate() ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 
  2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2)
- Pass that new variable as ready only to a script task (following is using C#) that will do what you want with the file.  The following code was modified from that gathered from [C# example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f67fbd86-df92-40ea-9264-e70e6a50c0d8/ssis-script-task-copy-files-with-wildcards?forum=sqlintegrationservices).  If C# is not preferable, you could also use a ForEach loop enumerated on the filename containing a system task to do the same.

> string FileWildCard = Dts.Variables["User::FileWildCard"].Value.ToString();
>   string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\dev01\E$\Data\Proc\Opt", @FileWildCard + "*.txt");
>   foreach (string file in files)
>   {
>     System.IO.File.Copy(file, @"\dev01\E$\Data\Proc\Opt test\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), true);
>   }

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: my time stamp varies everyday for the file. The lines RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("hh" , GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mi" , GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("ss" , GETDATE()), 2) will get me the current time. How do i configure it to get the changing file name everyday

Comment: Your issue is confusing.  Initially it sounded as though you wanted to just generate a file that dynamically includes the timestamp in the file name.  But now I do not understand.  What do you mean "configure it to get the changing file name every day"?  What is the "big picture" objective with the file generated?  Are you actually not generating it but trying to capture it from a directory based on just the date stamp part (ignoring the timestamp)?

Comment: yes i need to get a file from the folder ignoring the time stamp

Comment: In that case, I recommend that you define your file to a new variable with the value including just the first part of it (everything leading up to timestamp, but not including it).  Pass that variable to a script task (C#) and use that as a wildcard like that show in the following link where one or more files are copied.  For greater clarification, I'll update my earlier answer. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f67fbd86-df92-40ea-9264-e70e6a50c0d8/ssis-script-task-copy-files-with-wildcards?forum=sqlintegrationservices